# Simplify a probability

Tags: probability

So this is unfortunately straight out of my math book, and it is supposed to be an easy problem. But I haven't really grasped how you are supposed to simplify them.
[image: Cambridge IB math HL question]

If someone could explain(how am i supposed to move them around) question a or b I believe that's all i need.

Answer for Q1: P(x>4) Q2:P(y<=3)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post. Ref: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4932/290189

Comment: As a start, please tell us in English what you think is meant by "$P(x>2\cap x>4)$".

Comment: In the first question $x > 2 \cap x > 4$ means $x > 2$ and $x > 4$. This means we need to take $x > 4$ because taking $x >2$ doesn't make $x > 4$, but taking $x >4$ does make $x > 2$.

Comment: So you are saying that we take x>4 because every time that is true x>2 is also true? 
Does the same apply for question 2(since it says "or")? Because in that case we should be taking y<2 and not y<=3. @Euclidean

Comment: Precisely. In the second part, the $\cup$ means we can take the 'weakest' of the two conditions. So for $y \leq 3 \cup y < 2$ we can take $y \leq 3$. This is different to the $\cap$ case, because in the $\cap$ question we have to take the 'strongest' condition. Ie. The one which is satisfied by both $x > 2$ and $x > 4$.

Comment: @Euclidean aha! Thank you sir!

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I meant a & b, will edit...

Comment: For the first four problems, if it's of any help to your understanding, you could also plot the inequalities on a number line and then take the union and intersection of those regions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are multiple questions, just an image file and no context and explanation of the notation.

Comment: @phira what else do you want me to write? There's nothing to add... I don't (didn't) know how to solve them... If I knew what to do I wouldn't have asked for help...

Comment: You should have added what "P" means and what P(apple) means in this context and what it is that poses the problem for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be helpful to take a look at the [definitions](https://www.everythingmaths.co.za/maths/grade-10/10-probability/10-probability-04.cnxmlplus) of $\cup$ and $\cap$.

---

Therefore, for **(a)**:
$$P(x>2 \cap x>4)$$
This means the probability that **both** $x>2$ and $x>4$ are satisfied (Due to the $\cap$). This is only true when $x>4$, therefore we can simplify this to:

[image]

$$P(x>4)$$

---

For **(b)**:
$$P(y\leq 3 \cup y<2)$$
This means the probability that **at least one** of $y\leq 3$ and $y<2$ is satisfied (Due to the $\cup$). This is only true when $y\leq 3$, therefore:

[image]

$$P(y\leq 3)$$

---

Hope you can continue. It is very helpful to draw number lines for **(c)** and **(d)**. Note that some of these cannot be simplified.